Did Zapata ask a young revolutionary, "What is your name?" and then write that man's name on a piece of paper?
In the 1952 movie "Viva Zapata," Mexican dictator Diaz asks revolutionary Emiliano Zapata, “What is your name?” and then circles the name on a piece of paper.
Am I correct in remembering that later in the film, Zapata asks a young revolutionary, "What is your name?" and then writes that man's name on a piece of paper?

I can't remember the film, but the screenplay book says that there's a scene like this; https://i.sstatic.net/6ImT1hBM.png - https://i.sstatic.net/pBzyAs4f.png


later in the film, Zapata asks a young revolutionary, "What is your name?" and then writes that man's name on a piece of paper?

Almost, the man is not a revolutionary but a farmer come to complain about Zapata's brother.
Zapata does not write the name (as indicated by the screenplay images provided by Valorum) but rather circles the man's name from a list handed to him.
This is a re-enactment of when Zapata's name was circled by Diaz.


